# Regex after last slash select first digit separate sub-string of 1 or 2 letters

Tags: regex

I'm relatively new to RegEx and I'm struggling with making the following match and I hope that the community can help.

I have URLs in the following format:

https://somedomain.com/sub/SUBSITE/FOLDER/12345DR6789

Where I am interested in extracting specific digits from the identifier '12345DR6789' at the end of the string specifically the first numeric digit '1' and the string in the middle 'DR' that can be either 1 or 2 letters so the result for:

12345DR6789 = 1DR

Another example with a single letter:

72345A6789 = 7A

The format will always be the same and the length will vary based on whether there are 1 or 2 letters present.

I managed to get the letter(s) parsed using:

(?<=\d{5})(.*?)(?=\d{3,4}$)

But I don't know how to include/concat the first digit after the slash.

A different strategy might be to match everything after the last slash '72345A6789' and remove 4 digits on either side of the letter(s) but I'm at a loss of how to do that.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 capturing groups instead of using lookarounds. The lookaround in your example will only match a single value.

Taking the quantifiers `{5}` and `{3,4}` from the example pattern into account:

```
(\d)\d{4}([A-Z]{1,2})\d{3,4}$
```

In parts

- `(\d)` Capture **group 1**, match a digit
- `\d{4}` Match 4 digits
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[A-Z]{1,2}` Match 1-2 times A-Z
- `)` Close group 
  `\d{3,4}` Match 3-4 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lbyekb/1)

If the pattern should start with http:

```
^https?://\S+/(\d)\d{4}([A-Z]{1,2})\d{3,4}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0xlDzQ/1)

Comment: I might be missing something but I am having problems getting the RegEx engine (System.Text) to process the above RegEx correctly. 

If I click on the above RegEx demo "PCRE" is listed as the engine but even if I use that package in .NET it doesnt give a result (I have noticed that if you click away from the above PCRE engine in the demo and back again then it also fails in your example). 

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: @martingp I think that the the `/` is used as a delimiter. You can escape the forward slashes if that is the case https://regex101.com/r/ZILCvV/1

Comment: Ok after some further debugging I found the issue. The above demo returns a) Full match b) Group 1 and c) Group 2. The C# RegEx result is a) "Full match" - so is that by design or is possible to get the combination of Group 1 and 2 as the "Full match" which is the result I am after? Otherwise I need to deal with the group case specifically in code which is a bit messy. Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: @martingp as the pattern matches the full match with the 2 capturing groups, you could use those groups in the replacement like `$1$2` or `\1\2` depending what is supported. What is the tool or programming language?

Comment: Thanks for the input which is much appreciated. I use c# with the standard RegEx engine. I ended up writing a helper function so if more than one result is returned then each group result is combined the which works okay for my purpose.